# Creating a h file for this .cpp file

Tags: visual-c++

This is the content of the .cpp file. I want Parse to be runnable from a C# project.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "DateTimeParser.h"

using namespace std;

System::DateTime Parse(string myString)
{
    int year, month, day;
    sscanf_s(myString.c_str(), "%4d-%2d-%2d",&year, &month, &day);
    System::DateTime dateTime = System::DateTime(year,month,day);
    return dateTime;
}
```

How do i define the h file? I tried the following.

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

using namespace System;

ref class DTParser
{
    public:
        System::DateTime Parse(std::string myString);
};
```

I got this error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: DateTimeParser, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  DateTimeParser.cpp
1>DateTimeParser.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000001) DTParser::Parse
1>DateTimeParser.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000002) DTParser::main
1>\Debug\DateTimeParser.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: try changing the definition as System::DateTime DTParser::Parse(string myString) in your cpp file

Answer (score 0):

From what you are saying I assume that the problem is not the header file. The problem is that you did not compile your C++ code for the CLR.
You must put the C++ code in a separate assembly and activate the common language runtime support in the project settings.

Answer (score 0):

In your header file you have

`System::DateTime Parse(std::string myString);`

This could just be

`DateTime Parse(std::string myString);`

As the namespace is not needed